# How to Get a responce message from service and print that message using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ptc-windchill

I need to get a responce message from a service and print that message using batch file. I need to stop a windchill service and get that message and prints it, If service is properly stopped then I need to start the windchill service..

```
windchill stop
timeout /t 10 
windchill start
```

Above code will stop and start the service with Buffer time. But I need to get the message after service is stopped and prints that that message. and only if the service is properly stopped then i need to start my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I do not have `windchill` to see the results.

But as per the previous question's updated answer:

````
windchill stop
:wait
timeout /t 5 >nul 2>&1
windchill status | find /I "stopped"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo windchill successfully Stopped
  windchill start
  goto :eof
)
goto :wait
```
````